# generic interface that only allows objects that implement other interfaces

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface `A`, and wish to write an **generic** interface `B` such that any `T` that implements `B` must also have implemented both `A` and `Comparable`. `A` is not currently a generic interface.

Is this possible? Do I need to make A generic?
I had hoped to be able to write something like:

```
public interface B<T implements Comparable, A> {}
```

But this does not seem to work... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I do not believe this is a duplicate of the question that has been linked.

Comment: Is `B<T extends Comparable & A>` what you are looking for? Where the generic type must be of `Comparable` and `A`?

Comment: `interface B<T> implements A, Comparable` ?

Comment: @Mike, can you stick that in an answer so I can give you some points?

Comment: Are you sure you meant to say that `T` also implements `B`? Then you'd be looking for `interface B<T extends A & B<T> & Comparable<T>> `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for here are [multi-bounded generic types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html):

```
public interface B<T extends A & Comparable> {}
```

Note that if either of the bounded types is a `class` instead of an `interface`, it has to be the first bound defined after `extends`. Also, you cannot use multi-bounded generic types on more than one `class`(since there is no multiple-inheritance in Java)

Answer (score 1):

Just make B to extend A and Comparable.

```
public interface A {
    public void methodA();
}

public interface B<T> extends A, Comparable<T> {
    public T methodB();
}

public class BImpl<T> implements B<T> {
    @Override
    public T methodB() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void methodA() {

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(T o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```